# KDevelop not executing Hello World program

Tags: kdevelop, kdevelop4

I am using KDevelop 4.6.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.

At one point I saw the output of my hello world program, but now I can build it, but not execute it. That is, if I press the Execute button I am presented with a Launch Configurations dialog which gives me a choice of either a Global configuration or a PlayingAround configuration (my project name). However, no matter which configuration is chosen, nothing happens. No error message, no output, nothing.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on that "Add New..." button at the left-top corner. This would allow you to create a launch for any targets created with `add_executable` from CMake as well as arbitrary executable target.